# Quadratic Simultaneous equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

$$4x(x^2+y^2-1)=0$$ 
$$4y(x^2+y^2+1)=0$$
Solving Simultaneous equation 
$(x,y)=(0,0) ,(1,0)$ or $, (-1,0)$

I try to use substitution but couldnt find $x$ and $y$ properly, and (0,0) always be one of the solutions?

Comment: What are you asking here? The real solutions are $(0,0)$, $(\pm1,0)$ as you say.

Comment: Im asking how to get the solutions. First $x=0$ and $x^2+y^2-1=0$ so $y^2=1$ is this true?

Comment: For real number, $a, b$. if $ab=0$, the conclusion is $a=0$ or $b=$ rather than $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second equation, since $x^2+y^2 +1 > 0$, we have $y=0$

Substitute $y=0$ into the first equation, we end up with

$$4x(x^2-1)=0$$

Now we can solve for $x$.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer! $x^2+y^2+1=0$ is this become one of the solution(?)

Comment: For real number, $x^2+y^2+1 \geq 1$, so that equation never holds.

Comment: $4x(x^2+y^2-1)=0$ here as you said, $4x=0$ since $x^2+y^2-1>=0$ never holds, then i get $x=0$ then i put it in second equation, so i will get $y=0$ right?

Comment: hmmm $x^2+y^2+1 \geq 0$, $x^2+y^2-1$ might take value $0$. working from the second equation seems easier. You can conclude $y=0$ directly. Try substituting $y0$ into the first equation and solve for $x$.

Comment: ah yes but i mean from second equation, did you conclude $y=0$ because  $x^2+y^2+1>=0$ so it is not satisfied =0? after substituting to first equation, i got $x=0,x=-1,x=1$, so i already got all the solutions?

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Comment: is it possible to find the solutions using the first equation? $x=0$? then substitute to second equations. but i dont know how to find x=-1/1

Comment: Starting from the first equation, Isn't that what dxiv is doing?

Answer (score 0):

- If $x=0$ then the second equation gives $4y(y^2+1)=0 \implies y=0\,$, thus the solution $\boxed{(0,0)}$.
- Else if $x \ne0, y=0$ the first equation gives $4x(x^2-1)=0 \implies x=\pm1\,$, thus $\boxed{(\pm1, 0\,)}\,$.
- Otherwise if $x,y \ne 0\,$, dividing the first equation by $4x \ne 0$, the second one by $4y \ne 0$ and 
  <s>adding the two gives ...</s>  subtracting the two (*@LordSharktheUnknown's comment*) gives $2=0\,$, obviously impossible, so there are no further solutions in this case.

Comment: Or in the last case subtracting the equations you get gives $8=0$.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer! Do you get $x=0$ from the first equation? Then put in in second equation? And $y=0$ from second equation and put it in first equation?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Right, that's arguably an even better way to derive the contradiction.

Comment: @DevinaMuljono `Do you get x=0 from the first equation` No, I am just breaking it down by cases. If $x=0$ then the first equation is satisfied automatically, so I am only looking at the second one.

Comment: did you get $x=0$$y=0$ by assumption? but if $y=0$ and substitute to first equation i will get $x=1,x=-1,x=0$ too.. is this true?

Comment: @DevinaMuljono Not sure what you mean `by assumption`. You are solving a system for $x,y$. My answer simply broke it down into three mutually exclusive cases: either **(a)** $\,x=0\,$, or **(b)** $\,x \ne 0, y=0\,$, or **(c)** $x,y \ne 0\,$, and derived the solutions in each case. There was no other assumption introduced at any step.

Comment: @dxiv hmm okay thankyou so much for answering my question!!!